# What is a rolton?

Tags: monsters, adnd-1e, history-of-gaming

In 1999 I found a parody of The Twelves Days of Christmas to have a Dungeons & Dragons feel to it.
It wasn't until I started playing D&D in 2014 that I realised it was based on D&D when I finally understood the line "Six kobolds stumbling".

Another line is "Two rolton pelts".

Is a rolton a creature in D&D and if so, what is it?

Comment: Do you have a link to this? I can't find any song matching your description.

Comment: I tried to find it on line before I uploaded the question to check my spelling of rolton and couldn't find it. I have got the original print out though. It was down as The Twelve Hours of Solstice Day from Selected Music and Poetry from the Masses by Lord Auree Gyldanhand, et al.

Comment: On the twelfth hour of Solstice Day, My true gave to me: Twelve trolls invading, Eleven rangers mapping, Ten bards a-singing, Nine clerics rezzing, Eight empaths healing, Seven rouges a-picking, Six kobolds stumbling, Five temple deeds! Four silver wands, Three smooth stones, Two rolton pelts, And an acorn from a oak tree.

Comment: After some research, I'm going to go out on a limb and say that *whole song* is *Gemstone* inspired: even, for example, the [smooth stones](https://gswiki.play.net/mediawiki/index.php/Smooth_stone) are from that game.

Comment: Where do the smooth stones come in?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **rolton** comes from the various incarnations of the MMORPG [*Gemstone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GemStone_IV) video game, dating back at least to 1988. A rolton is apparently a sheep-like opponent that can be skinned for its somewhat valuable pelt.

The *Gemstone* wiki describes a [rolton](https://gswiki.play.net/mediawiki/index.php/Rolton) as

> covered with a dirty, matted, disgusting-looking grey pelt that might once have been white and is still abysmally smelly. However, it isn't this trait alone that gives him such a terrifying appearance. As the animal bleats at you, it is then you get a view of the 'maw of death', with its long, curved incisors that gnash and gnaw. The critter has some nasty-looking hooves as well.

One depiction of the rolton has it looking like this:

[image: Baa!]

How accurate this depiction is debatable, *Gemstone* being a text-based game.

Comment: The image and description is fine for my purposes. I'd always wondered about a rolton since then. They are mentioned in two other carols from the same source. One is called "Banthos Got Run Over by a Rolton" and the other is called "Old Rone Wehnimer" and starts off, Old Rone Wehnimer looked out, On the Bay of Darkstone. Roltons frolicked all about...